# Adding help icon to WinForms form titlebar

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

Some Windows native applications have a question mark icon on the title bar. It's usually at the right edge, just near the close button. How can I do this in a C# WinForms application? I'd like a solution that works in Windows XP onward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the form's [HelpButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbutton.aspx) property to True.  You also need to have the MaximizeButton and MinimizeButton properties set to False.