# Detect when help button is pressed in title bar of Windows Form?

Tags: c#

My c# console application displays a Windows Form for user to login, I've added a Help button to the top of the login Form just in case any users have any questions [image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is have a `MessageBox()` popup when user presses the Help button. I've done some research and still haven't been able to find any working solutions. Any help would greatly be appreciated!
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you seen [how-to-include-help-in-title-bar-of-winform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474663/) or [adding-help-icon-to-winforms-form-titlebar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112472/)?

Comment: @slackmuggle Not my question at all. I was asking how to add a HelpButton click event. I got it working though...

Comment: If you got it working and the provided answer did not match what you were looking for it would be nice to have your solution as an answer so that others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729172(v=vs.85).aspx) the way to handle this is to process the windows [WM_HELP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774305(v=vs.85).aspx) message:

> **DS_CONTEXTHELP**
>
> Includes a question mark in the title bar of the dialog box. When the user clicks the question mark, the cursor changes
>   to a question mark with a pointer. If the user then clicks a control
>   in the dialog box, the control receives a **WM_HELP** message. The control
>   should pass the message to the dialog box procedure, which should call
>   the function using the **HELP_WM_HELP** command. The help application
>   displays a pop-up window that typically contains help for the control.
>
> Note that **DS_CONTEXTHELP** is only a placeholder. When the dialog box is
>   created, the system checks for **DS_CONTEXTHELP** and, if it is there,
>   adds **WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP** to the extended style of the dialog box.
>   **WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP** cannot be used with the **WS_MAXIMIZEBOX** or
>   **WS_MINIMIZEBOX** styles.

In brief, you need to implement a WndProc method for the controls in your form (which unfortunately will need to be individually derived from their base classes):

```
const int WM_HELP = 0x53;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_HELP:
            // Your handler here
            break;
        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
     }
}
```